# MCNP multiple cell sources with a lattice

Tags: montecarlo

I've been trying for a while to get a lattice-cell-source running with an ordinary cell-source in MCNP. I can get them both working separately but when I try and combine them I get the following `fatal error: distribution 1 for cel is the wrong kind`

My source code is as follows:

```
SDEF  PAR=SF 
      CEL=D9 $ Fatal error. distribution 1 for cel is the wrong kind
      X D11 
      Y D12
      Z D13
c
DS9 S 4 10
DS11 S 1 14
DS12 S 2 15
DS13 S 3 16
c
c ---- Lattice cell source-----
SI4 L (3<2[-5:5 -5:5 -10:10]<5) 
SP4 1  2540r 
SI1 -0.12 0.12
SP1 0 1
SI2 -0.12 0.12
SP2 0 1
SI3 -0.12 0.12
SP3 0 1
c
c ---- Separate cell source ---
SI10 L 25
SP10 1
SI14 22.8 27.2
SP14 0 1
SI15 -2.2 2.2
SP15 0 1
SI16 -2.2 2.2
SP16 0 1
```

Do any of you know how to declare an embedded source along with an ordinary cell source? Image of the lattice and cell source: light blue indicates source material:
[image: Image of the lattice and cell source: light blue indicates source material] Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a colleague we have found a solution, included below. It involves including an FCEL dependency on each distribution, as well as calling the cells directly within the CEL distribution without adding another D-card. Then ALL of the cells must be included in the following distributions.

```
SDEF PAR=SF
CEL=D9
X=FCEL D11
Y=FCEL D12
Z=FCEL D13
c
c
SI9 L (3<2[-5:5 -5:5 -10:10]<5) 25
c Cells 3 and 25 are called (3 is in the lattice notation)
SP9 1 2540r 2079
c assigning importance to each cell: lattice ~55%, PuO ball ~45%
DS11 S 1 2540r 14
c First 2541 cells have D1 attached, the last cell is attached to D14
DS12 S 2 2540r 15
c First 2541 cells have D2 attached, the last cell is attached to D15
DS13 S 3 2540r 16
c First 2541 cells have D3 attached, the last cell is attached to D16
c
c ---- Lattice cell source-----
SI1 -0.12 0.12
SP1 0 1
SI2 -0.12 0.12
SP2 0 1
SI3 -0.12 0.12
SP3 0 1
c
c ---- Separate cell source ---
SI14 22.8 27.2
SP14 0 1
SI15 -2.2 2.2
SP15 0 1
SI16 -2.2 2.2
SP16 0 1
```

It's always tricky trying to do so without much context.